# How I serialize a blockchain without using Async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying serialize connection function of mysql drive. But when I did run my function, nodejs make async calls and I can't retrieve the correct value of result. 
How I can run connection.connect in serialize? I can't use async/await to resolve this problem because the result of a function will turn a promise.

```js
function a(){

 var result = "false";
 
 connection = dbConnection.getConnection();
 console.log("test1");
 
 connection.connect(function (err) {
  console.log("test2");
  result = "true";
 });

 console.log("end of function");
 return result;
}

console.log(a());
```

log:

**test1**

**end of function**

**false**

**test2**

Comment: To use `async/await` you would want your function to return a promise.

Comment: The ONLY thing you can do is learn how to code async. Either learn how to use callbacks properly or how to use promises or how to use async/await. Any other way you want to do it IS IMPOSSIBLE.

Comment: There is no way around this problem without asynchronicity unfortunately. The good thing is asynchronicity isn't hard to implement at all.

Comment: Read [Up and Running with Asynchronous JavaScript](https://medium.com/@rcepeda1993/async-js-the-complete-guide-670b4cf906c6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score -1):

```
function a() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const connection = dbConnection.getConnection();

    connection.connect(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        reject();
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
}

async function isConnected() {
  let hasConnection = false;
  try {
    const connected = await a();
    hasConnection = true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('You are not connected');
  }

  return hasConnection;
}

isConnected();
```

Comment: This won't work. It is a syntax error to use `await` outside of `async`

Comment: Why do you use both resolve/reject AND a boolean flag at the same time? This is redundant. And the `connected` constant is useless as it is never false.

Comment: @slebetman right you gotta put the await inside of a function scope. Will fix

Comment: @Danilinn why can't you use promises?

Comment: in my application the result of my function can not be a promise, it has to be the pure result

Comment: At least don't reassign `connected`. It's const even

Comment: @MaxBaldwin because I have an external function that will read my function a, and it can not open that result as promise. I am suing rcp protocol

Comment: @Danilinn, with `async/await` you don't have to handle promises in their normal `.then().catch()` manner. My point is your function that will be read by an external function has to return a promise so that you can make your asynchronous connection call synchronous. The external function does not need to be exposed to or handle that promise.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin the result of isConnected() is a promise, and i only read the status using .then().catch(), but in my application i cant do this. I need the pure status

Comment: @Danilinn that's not true. Look at my example above